# Final warning - afraid of losing my job

Tags: termination, distractions

At my job I have been there for just over a year.  My manager gave me a final written warning because people complained that I visit their desk too often when looking for more work and cause them to become distracted.

Yesterday, someone else complained and I had to have a meeting with my manager. I am aware that I have made mistakes.

I have very bad ADHD so I recently bought focusing vitamins to try and help but haven’t had a chance to use them yet.

At work everyone else in my position now sits together so they are able to divide up work and get more easily. I sit by myself to try and avoid distractions but now it’s hard when I run out of work because everyone doesn’t always have their email open. Because of it I feel extremely isolated.

I am so scared of losing my job. It’s really the only thing I have. I have lost so much personally in the past year and I can’t lose this too.

Is there anything I can do to keep my job? Anything I can say?

I’m also looking at ways to be able to stay focused at work.

I have a medical condition that allows me to take breaks when I’m not feeling well so I could take a break if needed.

Comment: Your manager will fire you for looking for work? Just proves managers are definitely promoted using the Peter Principle. They must be able to have a better system of allocating work.

Comment: How is work normally assigned? Is there a backlog of unassigned work items available from which you can self-assign tasks? When your colleagues did tell you what you could work on, did you actually do that work? Have you talked to your manager about what you should do when you run out of assigned work?

Comment: How is it that other people know how to get work but you have to bother people for hours begging for work? Do people not trust your work quality?

Comment: Are you being treated for your ADHD? I'm not talking about focusing vitamins, whatever those are, but actually seeing a doctor?

Comment: When you run out of work, go to your manager to find more work instead of going to your coworkers.

Comment: "final written warning" - this implies there is a longer history than you tell here.  Perhaps you would like to add some of that?  In any case, you should start your job search because this might just be a matter of time passing for procedure.

Comment: And "very bad ADHD" require prescription medicine from your doctor, not vitamins.  I also suggest you explain your job situation to your doctor, you might qualify for sick leave.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen This is not the first question OP has asked about these issues- you can find a lot of background on their other questions.

Comment: Do you know what you're supposed to do when you need more work? If not, why have you not asked?

Comment: @studoku ah, and I’ve seen at least one before.  I think this bridge is burned.

Comment: Wait -- OP got a *previous* ["final written warning" on a different issue in May of this year](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/172366/what-should-i-do-i-got-a-final-written-warning). How did that work out? OP, are you finding the answers here on SE to your other questions helpful?

Answer (score 18):

**Pull work from the backlog, not your coworkers**

How are you currently assigned work?  In software, we have a "backlog" concept where low priority work is written down and done as people are idle.  Even outside of software development, there are task like doing inventory that you can do without pestering your coworkers.  Talk to your manager about task you can do by yourself in your downtime by yourself.

If work is assigned on-the-fly, with no system that tracks work to be done, then find a new job.  This company won't last long.

> I have very bad ADHD so I recently bought focusing vitamins to try and help but haven’t had a chance to use them yet.

Do you have an actual diagnosis, or did you self diagnose?  I doubt vitamins are what a doctor prescribes.  To get accommodations you'll need an actual diagnosis from a doctor.  Even with a legitimate diagnosis, they can still fire you.  The company will just have to show they made reasonable accommodations.

I'm concerned you believe just saying something like "I have bad knees and need to sit down and ADHD, so I need to be alone" to your boss is all you need to do.  It isn't!  You need an official diagnosis AND you must work with your company to determine what is reasonable.  The company can still fire you if your conditions prevent or hinder you from doing your job.

Begin job searching now, it sounds like the process to fire you was sit in motion a while ago.

**EDIT**

OP, if you think you have ADHD, please consider going to a doctor and getting real medication for it.  The commenters agree with me.

Comment: Vitamins are generally a go to item in the alternative medicine field.  If you are now at a point you're trying to treat yourself with them, odds are you have lost your grip on reality in the medical sense.  I have a Biology degree, and I could talk about vitamins and their role in the body, but odds are it's too late.  You have to unlearn most of what you've probably been learning.  To point, the entire medical field makes tons of money treating people, and they all are willing to steal patients from each other.  If vitamins cured, they'd poach their competitors patients with them.

Comment: And in case I wasn't clear, "alternative medicine" mostly means "instead of medicine."  Medical practices are constantly interested in cheaper, effective treatments.  If it worked, it wouldn't be alternative for long.

Comment: Focusing vitamins are not designed to treat ADHD.  Seek medical advice on how to properly treat your diagnosis

Comment: Agree time to find a new job asap.

Comment: Noteworthy is that, based on grammar in the OP, I'm guessing OP is not a native English speaker.  It's possible  "vitamins" is a  translation of the word in OP's native language,  when we would use "drugs" or "medication" in English.  Let's not be too harsh.

Answer (score 1):

1. Even if you lose your job, keep in mind that you must remain positive.

> It’s really the only thing I have. I have lost so much personally in the past year and I can’t lose this too.

Don't think that if you lose your job you are worthless. It happens to everybody and remind yourself that the next job will come sooner or later.

2. Instead of walking to others desks when you run out of tasks you should

- Talk with your manager about the status of your tasks and ask him to get more tasks
- Learn something new that may help the company
- Deep dive into the current products and systems of the company

Answer (score 1):

> At work everyone else in my position now sits together so they are able to divide up work and get more easily. I sit by myself to try and avoid distractions but now it’s hard when I run out of work because everyone doesn’t always have their email open. Because of it I feel extremely isolated.

This is a much bigger deal than you think it is.  You've basically isolated yourself (or been isolated) from the rest of your team.  They work collaboratively, you work by yourself.  They communicate by  talking to  each other, you communicate by email only.  You see where the  problem is.  You should fix this, and sit with your team.

Regarding distractions, I don't know how ADHD works, but ideally if you  are focused on a task then you shouldn't be able to be distracted easily.  If you are not focused on a task, then perhaps you should chat with your manager on tasks that can keep you focused, or find another job where those tasks exist  instead  of your  current one where they don't.  You can also try things like wearing headphones and listening to music to block out distracting noises or whatnot.

> I have very bad ADHD so I recently bought focusing vitamins to try and help but haven’t had a chance to use them yet.

By this I  presume you mean "medication" and not "vitamins".  If you have serious ADHD (a real, medical, diagnosable  condition), then you should not take "vitamins",  which are over-the-counter supplements  for people with mild  conditions; you should go to the doctor and get medication to actually help you with your problem.  If you do not have serious enough ADHD  to get diagnosed and get proper medication, then you should not use that as an excuse to not do your work  properly; plenty of people (myself included) get distracted at work, but we manage to  do our jobs well  despite that,  and it takes self-discipline and not making your distraction issue somebody else's problem.  In any case, do not take "vitamins"; take "medication",  but only with proper medical advice and a proper prescription.  Do not try to self-diagnose and self-medicate, that's how you get into big trouble.

> I have a medical condition that allows me to take breaks when I’m not feeling well so I could take a break if needed.

Do  **not** do this.  The thing about taking breaks  is that it  causes [context switching](https://blog.rescuetime.com/context-switching/).  When you leave your task and go take a break, you context switch from your work and  to getting coffee.  Then when you come back, you have to context switch back from "break mode" to "work mode".  This  causes distractions and  can trigger your ADHD to make you want to do something else instead of work.  Focus on your work, don't take breaks in the middle of your tasks (as much as you can; obviously if you have to pee then go pee, but try to minimize your breaks as much as  possible/reasonable),  and you'll find yourself context-switching less which should  help to minimize your distractions and triggers to your ADHD.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems similar to this, though not so extreme.

The other answers regarding finding a backlog are useful.

This is also an opportunity to take the fact you've completed your work and use it to your benefit - Send the email asking if there's anything else you can do, to the coworkers, and then also send one to your manager saying "Hey, I'm caught up on the queue, let me know if there's anything else we want to work on."

Work on any personal innovation ideas you might have.

Talk up people in other departments maybe (who aren't busy) on what their goals might be for integrations and work with your department... get an idea of what people's issues are and what you can do to solve them...

You can take this opportunity to become more of a team player, and knocking out your team's goals... but you need to consider more whether someone is busy.

When you walk up to a person's desk, the implication is whatever you need, they must drop what they're doing to entertain it. Email and IM is much better if it's low priority - and not having anything to do seems like a low priority issue, as far as, what's been requested has been completed.

First thing you do, before anything else, is just find out if your manager has anything they need you to work on.

Manager's usually have a significant portion of their salaries made up (30%+ sometimes, this is partly why they're always so stressed!) of bonuses for specific projects. Find out if there's a goal he has that you can work to help complete.

If not... Enjoy the extra time to yourself?

It can be isolating, but work is not a social place. If you try to be too social, and it's impeding others work, in management's view, you're actually causing a problem, and you might unknowingly be stressing out your teammates who have to catch up on work afterwards.

-- Stop taking 'vitamins' to solve the issue - real medication, or behavioral therapy, something that can actually solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the root of your problem is that you're getting up and bothering your other co-workers? Is that all of the complaints you get from your boss?

First, who is your direct supervisor? I would go to that person and say you do not have any work and that you are looking for work.

Second, I would try to get an understanding from your boss. It may be too late right now since you gotten so many warnings. So your boss might not believe any excuses right now since you haven't brought it up until now when you're about to be let go of.

Right now your best choice is to keep a low profile and do what you're told. If you keep bringing up complaints and excuses, it might backfire since you haven't brought it up before. Once everything calms down, and you done work successfully, I would try to have a one-on-one with your boss. Tell him that sometimes you walk around talking to co-workers because you are looking for work and you wish to know who you can talk to.

Finally do not worry about getting fired. While it is a major stressor, I would just continue to go to work and do your best. It sounds like thus far the only thing you done wrong is being yourself. Next time, just be yourself but also make sure others know what your motives are. don't just walk around talking and chatting to people asking what they're doing without any sort of explanation.

If ultimately you are let go of, just look for a new job and learn from your mistakes.